# How to validate JSON from AJAX in PHP. Using JSON in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

user is posting by AJAX that data package in JS:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("title", title);
data.append("from", from);
data.append("to", to);
data.append("what", what);
data.append("why", why);
data.append("milestones", JSON.stringify(milestones_object));
```

A milestones object looks like this:

```
{
  "0": {
    "0": {
      "title": "1",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "title": "2",
      "favorite": true,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "3",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "title": "a",
    "favorite": false
  },
  "1": {
    "0": {
      "title": "1",
      "favorite": true,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "title": "2",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "3",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "3": {
      "title": "4",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "4": {
      "title": "5",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "title": "b",
    "favorite": true
  },
  "2": {
    "0": {
      "title": "4",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "title": "3",
      "favorite": true,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "2": {
      "title": "2",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "3": {
      "title": "1",
      "favorite": false,
      "progress": 0
    },
    "title": "c",
    "favorite": false
  }
}
```

I want to validate that data in my PHP webservice. There is no problem with standard variables, but what with JSON? What if some angry user will send additional fields that don't match with my project idea? Can we filter that JSON by something like delete_additional_json_fields($json_obj, $fillable_fields)? How to easly validate each property of that JSON? How to work with that in most proper way?

Please for help.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @bxN5 Ok, I know that function and what with that?

Comment: decode your json to php array and validate as you want

Comment: OK but how how to delete additional fields that angry user added? i need to did it befor put it into mysql.

Comment: for example, you have a list of valid fields? fields it will be keys of array, you can chek if key is not valid -  delete this key from the array